Why am I having GPU related issues on Lenovo Thinkpad P51 when connected to an external monitor?
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P51. Below are my specs:

Intel Core i7 7820HQ
16GB RAM
Nvidia Quadro M1200
Intel HD 630
Windows 11

I updated Nvidia driver from 535 to 550 drivers. The issue is when I connect laptop to an external monitor (with HDMI, Displayport or Thunderbolt) the system freezes. The cursor goes away and my external monitor shows no signal message. This was also happening on Windows 10. I have to unplug the video cable and force shutdown by holding the power button.
Its working fine on 535 without any issues. However, on Nvidia's website it says the Quadro M1200 is compatible with the 550 drivers. If I switch the graphics setting from hybrid to discrete only in BIOS, then it works without any issue. But I don't think thats the best way forward as that will have significant impact on battery and thermals in my opinion. I have contacted Nvidia over this issue and am waiting for their response.
Please help me out. Anybody who is using a Lenovo Thinkpad P51 or somebody who has gone through something similar, what needs to be done?

Do you use graphics drivers provided by Lenovo? If not, get the recommended drivers for your laptop from the Lenovo webpage.

Quadro M1200 is indeed supported by the 550 driver branch in Windows 11. However, your computer overall ISN'T officially compatible with Windows 11. That alone can result in unexpected problems such as the one you're experiencing.

@ChanganAuto I don't believe that its Windows 11 compatibility issue because I was facing the same issue on Windows 10.

Sounds like there may be a bug or limitation in the 550 driver branch causing Optimus/MSHybrid to not work appropriately. A future driver update may correct the behavior, or it may be the case of some functionality being depreciated due to age, although this is less likely with an "only" 7 year-old GPU.
Try R560, which is also supported by Quadro M1200: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/details/230555/
In the event that R560 doesn't improve the behavior, there's not much else to do besides what you've already uncovered:

If you need driver features from the 550 branch, set the option for the discrete GPU in firmware at the cost of reduced battery life and higher thermals
If you don't need driver features from the 550 branch, use an older working driver


I guess I will stick with the 535 branch. Don't want to experiment with the R560. Don't know what kind of bugs that will introduce as thats New Feature Branch. Everything was fine until Davinci Resolve released its latest version. And that version requires latest Nvidia drivers. Right now with the 535 branch its only giving me OpenCL option in API. In the previous versions I had CUDA which is obviously the prefered option. Guess I will rollback to the previous version of Davinci as well for now.

The New Feature Branch isn't a beta driver service, the drivers aren't more likely to include bugs. It's just a release cadence to say, reduce the number of driver pushes an IT department may push in an enterprise setting: https://docs.nvidia.com/ai-enterprise/planning-resources-release-branches/latest/release-branches.html

I tried installing the New Feature Branch (560) but same issue as on 550 drivers. I guess for the M1200 on Thinkpad P51, 535 driver branch is the way to go. There must be a bug or limitation on the 550 and 560 driver branch. It wasnt so a few months ago. Because I only had the 550 drivers installed.

Your post seems to indicate that you only ever had the 535 driver working, are you sure 550 was working previously? If so, that fairly radically changes things, I would start to think it was some other update and not a driver bug.

Quite the opposite. I actually had the Nvidia RTX Experience which would update the drivers when they were available. I had the option to notify me when new drivers were available. I only ever had the 550 drivers until this bug started. I initially thought it was something Nvidia RTX Enterprise that was doing. Maybe its installing Beta drivers. So I got rid of it. And tried installing the previous versions. I don't quite remember how I landed on the 535 drivers. I guess maybe somebody on some forum suggested to maybe try this as he was also facing issues the 550 drivers.
